# Python: for range not working as i planed with replace function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to censor some words in a letter (email_two).

I try to use "for" function but it don't go through all of the word in variable `proprietary_terms`. please tell why it happens.

I checked some things and i am curious why this range return `NONE` at the end

proprietary_terms = ["she", "personality matrix", "sense of self", "self-preservation", "learning algorithm", "her", "herself"]

```
def censor_two(email_two, proprietary_terms):
   for x in proprietary_terms:
      if x in email_two:
       censor = email_two.replace(x,"XXXX"):
  return censor
```

It returns censored email but only with first word censored "she", and I don't know why. I know other method of doing this but i am curious why this not works.

Comment: It's not clear ... can you give us an example what should be the output ?

Comment: try this > for x in range(len(proprietary_terms)): , then use proprietary_terms[x]

Comment: The `replace` function returns a copy of the string. I think in this case you'll want to continuously iterate on the replacement. Otherwise, you'll always be getting the redacted version where only occurrences of the last word in `proprietary_terms` are censored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use re which is the regex module. Also, have corrected a couple of things in your code:

- Changed the case where you keep replacing the initial string with new string, which would cause only the last proprietary term to be replaced:

  ```
  censor = email_two.replace(x,"XXXX")
  ```
- Code:

  ```
  import re

  def censor(email_two, proprietary_terms):
      result=email_two
      for i in proprietary_terms:
          result=re.sub(i,"xxxx",result)
      return result
  ```

Result

```
    >>>print(censor("ahjksgdn ahksdjha dashdj asdas dasdsa dsa",["das","dsa"]))
    >>>ahjksgdn ahksdjha xxxxhdj asxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx
```